# How to get windows 2008server r2 DHCP to hand out an IP to a PXE-booting client

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp, pxe-boot

I really need some help here, Im trying to get a client to PXE-boot using WDS from a 2008 server R2. I've set up a DHCP scope from

- 10.0.0.11 - 10.0.0.20
- 255.255.255.0

The server is handing out IPs to the client when it's booted up, but when it's booting it searches for DHCP, and after about 45sec it returns "No DHCP or proxyDHCP offers were recieved"

The WDS-role is set up to accept any client, but i've also added the client to computers in AD based on the GUID.

The NIC on the client is Broadcom netxtreme 1.

Any clues to what i am doing wrong would be greately appriciated.

Comment: So you want WDS or DHCP to hand out IPs? They both can, and you should only have one configured. There are Pros and Cons to each.

Comment: I can? Didn't notice. Do you mean multicast? It doesnt really matter to me, as long as it works.

Comment: @ChrisS I think I found the option you are referring to; http://bayimg.com/laECfAAdJ

Answer (score 2):

A regular DHCP server only provides an IP, a mask, and some other DHCP options. a PXE enabled DHCP server additionally provides the IP address of the TFTP server and the name of the first file to retrieve by a net booting station (NBP=Net boot program)
If you already are using Microsoft's DHCP server you have to configure it to hand out information needed for PXE booting by ticking the appropriate WDS configuration checkboxes:

[image]